# Which are files and changes for creating a ListTemplate in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: development

I want to create a ListTemplate in sharepoint 2010.I have done the following changes to element.xml

```
<ListTemplate
 Name="doclib"
 Type="1116"
 BaseType="1"
 OnQuickLaunch="FALSE"
 SecurityBits="11"
 Sequence="110"
 DisplayName="Sample"
 Description="Library to store data."
 Image="/_layouts/images/itdl.png"
 NewPage= "SL/Pages/XSLnew.aspx"
 Category="Libraries"
 DocumentTemplate="101"/>
```

Is there any other files and changes i have to consider?Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created the [list Element Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462947%28v=office.14%29.aspx) , but you still have to deploy it as a feature.

This [Blog entry](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/create-custom-list-templates-in-caml/) should help you out.

Comment: OK.Is List Template and List Definition same?

Comment: No List Definitions are not the same as List Elements. Check here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466023(v=office.14).aspx